# How do you make a bar chart when each datapoint has multiple values?

Tags: categories, multi-select

I am using excel and have data with a column where each cell can contain multiple values, like the following:

| Person | Interests |
| --- | --- |
| Person 1 | football, yoga, hiking |
| Person 2 | ice hockey |
| Person 3 | football, yoga |
| Person 4 | ice hockey, badminton |

Now i would like a bar chart that show how many of each interest these persons have, so a bar chart showing the following data:

| Interest | Count |
| --- | --- |
| football | 2 |
| yoga | 2 |
| hiking | 1 |
| ice hockey | 2 |
| badminton | 1 |

I know how to do this if each cell only has one value, then i use a pivot table and a pivot chart. But when it is multiple values in each cell this doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is transform your data/table so that each item is on it's own row, and then you could apply your pivot table to create what you need.

Click on a cell and then Ctrl-T.

Go to Data -> Get & Transform Data -> From Table/Range

[image]

Select the Column. Select Split Column by Delimiter. Choose "Comma". In the Split Column dialog, click on Advanced Options.
In the Split Into section, choose Rows. Click OK

[image]

Click Close & Load

[image]

Now do you Pivot Table and make the bar chart form that table

[image]